# Limit of p-norms of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

$f$ is a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $f \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$. Let
$$
  M_n = \left( \int_a^b f (x)^n dx \right)^{1/n}.
$$
Show $\lim_n M_n = \sup \{ f(x) \mid x \in [a,b] \}$.

Comment: Did you try to find duplicates? What about adding what you tried?

Comment: Try first to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a^n+b^n+c^n)^{1/n}=\max(a,b,c)$ for non-negative $a,b,c$, following the same ideas as robjohns answer. Then the more complicated case in function space should be manageable.

Comment: Continuity is unnecessary, as shown in the answers to [this same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181592/).

Comment: As Did points out, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181592).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M=\sup\{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}$. We know that

$$ M_{n}\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}M^{n}\right)^{1/n}=(M^{n}(b-a))^{1/n}=M(b-a)^{1/n}.$$

Let $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have $\lim M_{n}\leq M$.

On the other hand, let $y\in [a,b]$ such that $f(y)=M$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|\leq\delta$, we have $f(x)\geq M-\epsilon$. Then

$$M_{n}=\left(\int_{a}^{b}f^{n}\right)^{1/n}\geq \left(\int_{[y-\delta,y+\delta]}f^{n}\right)^{1/n}\geq \left(\int_{[y-\delta,y+\delta]}(M-\epsilon)^{n}\right)^{1/n}=(M-\epsilon)(2\delta)^{1/n}.$$

As $n\rightarrow \infty$, then $\lim M_{n}\geq M-\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $\lim M_{n}\geq M$.

Comment: Could we adapt this proof if $f \in L^{\infty}([a,b])$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=\sup\limits_{[a,b]}\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\int_a^bf(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/n}
&\le \left(\int_a^bs^n\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/n}\\
&=s(b-a)^{1/n}
\end{align}
$$
If $c\lt s$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\int_a^bf(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/n}
&\ge c\,|\{x:f(x)\ge c\}|^{1/n}\\
\end{align}
$$
By the Squeeze theorem
$$
c\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_a^bf(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/n}\le s
$$
Since $c\lt s$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_a^bf(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/n}=\sup_{[a,b]}\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}
$$

Comment: Is this an official policy of the site that moderators encourage endless duplicates (duplicates of questions and, unsurprisingly, duplicates of answers)?

Comment: @Did: I seached a bit, and not finding anything easily, I couldn't chastise the OP for not searching. If you were able to find a duplicate, would you mind mentioning it in a comment to the question, please?

Comment: An example: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181592/. I am pretty sure there are more, and slightly surprised that simply reading the question did not ring a bell. // While we are at it, do you see a way to clean the mess at [this quite related page](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/92147)?

Comment: @Did: I know I have seen proofs of this before, and I don't doubt there are other proofs on MSE beside the one you cited, but I don't think I have answered or edited any of them, so I was not able to find them quickly. I will look at the related page.

Comment: @Did: all I can really do on the related page is to urge the OP to accept a correct answer. I have done this, but just as people are allowed to upvote incorrect answers, they are allowed to accept incorrect answers. We'll see if my comment has any effect.

Comment: OK. We'll see. Perhaps the ♦ will have magical effects...